# How find specific code occurrences in java code with sonar rule

Tags: java, sonarqube

I wish to give developers suggestion that for example: System.currentTimeMillis() is not recommended and provide some comments with alternative solutions.

AFAIK there is no such sonar rule, should I create a new one or there is an option to parametrize existing one?

I found that xpath for java is no longer supported, so am I right that writing custom rule is the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for template rule [S2253](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2253), which allows you to flag calls to a specific method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [example](https://github.com/2cvmoehre/just-another-sonar-ruleset/blob/0f21b1fab126dac4b7418590e294063d7e8cfa55/src/main/java/de/gracefulsoft/sonar/rules/NoObjectWaitRule.java) of setting custom method warnings using sonar:

> ```
> @Rule(key = "NoObjectWaitRule",
>         name = "NoObjectWaitRule",
>         description = "You should not use classic wait/notify mechanism. Instead use Java Concurrency API.",
>         priority = Priority.MAJOR,
>         tags =
>         {
>             "bad-practice"
>         })
> public class NoObjectWaitRule extends DisallowedMethodCheck
> {
>
>    public NoObjectWaitRule()
>     {
>         super.setClassName("java.lang.Object");
>         super.setMethodName("wait");
>         super.setAllOverloads(true);
>     }
>
> }
> ```